# Keep track of attributes over time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a collection of Documents each having a "value" and I want to be able to track the value over time, my first idea is to create a snapshot of the document in before_save and then do a group_by {|t| t.created_at.hour} on those snapshots to create a line chart afterwards. 
This should work, any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongoid gem has a module called `Mongoid::Versioning`.  Just include it in your model, like this:

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Versioning
end
```

That will give you access to all previous versions via `@instance.versions`.

http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/extras.html#versioning

Comment: Sweet! Thank you so much for the link as well. For some reason i went reinventing the wheel again.